# Execute SQL on CSV files via JDBC

Tags: java, sql, text, jdbc, csv

I need to apply an SQL query to CSV files (comma-separated text files). My SQL is predefined from another tool, and is not eligible to change. It may contain embedded selects and table aliases in the FROM part.

For my task I have found two **open-source** (this is a project requirement) libraries that provide JDBC drivers:

1. [CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/)
2. [XlSQL](https://xlsql.dev.java.net/)
3. [JBoss Teiid](http://www.jboss.org/teiid)
4. Create an Apache Derby DB, load all CSVs as tables and execute the query.

These are the problems I encountered:

1. it does not accept the syntax of the SQL (it uses internal selects and table aliases). Furthermore, it has not been maintained since 2004.
2. I could not get it to work, as it has as dependency a SAX Parser that causes exception when parsing other documents. Similarly, no change since 2004.
3. Have not checked if it supports the syntax, but seems like an overhead. It needs several entities defines (Virtual Databases, Bindings). From the mailing list they told me that last release supports runtime creation of required objects. Has anyone used it for such simple task (normally it can connect to several types of data, like CSV, XML or other DBS and create a virtual, unified one)?
4. Can this even be done easily?

From the 4 things I considered/tried, only 3 and 4 seem to me viable. Any advice on these, or any other way in which I can query my CSV files?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SQL is predefined and cannot be changed your best option is to load your CSV into a database and run queries against it.

Apache Derby is a viable option, so are [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), which even has a [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/csv-storage-engine.html) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Does your SQL use any proprietary functions / extensions? If so, that may limit your choices.

Comment: Yes, it uses substring and concatenations.

Answer (score 9):

I would load the data into HSQL (HypersonicSQL). Pure Java, correct SQL, well-proven. Pretty much anything else has a bigger footprint.

Comment: In fact HSQLDB is the only suggested solution that can open an existing CSV file as an SQL table. It allows both performing SQL queries directly on the CSV file and updating the records.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir what if csv file I want to process is very large in terms of 5 to 10 GB??

Comment: I did not try files that big with HSQL, but the documentation says the largest one is 8 TB (T, not G). You need to use CREATE CACHED TABLE to not keep the data in memory.
http://hsqldb.org/web/hsqlFAQ.html#FAQ

Comment: take a look at HSQL -> Text Tables: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/texttables-chapt.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd say embedded db. I'd suggest either Javadb (Derby built into the Java API) or H2 if you don't care about pulling the extra dependency.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to treat csv files as databases from within a Java program, you should look at the [h2 database engine.](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)  It has really nice support for reading/writing CSV files and working with in-memory databases. It's a successor to hsql, faster and with added features.  You can read about the csv support in the h2 tutorial.

Comment: You can read how easy this is to do using h2 in a Groovy script in this blog post:

http://bayesianconspiracy.blogspot.com/2010/02/executing-arbitrary-sql-on-csv-files.html

Answer (score 2):

maybe a bit late, sorry for that.

I've been developing the [csvjdbc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/) for over a year now and since a few weeks I've got "administrator" rights on that project so I've been able to release the most recent version I had produced.  it does all "we" need (we: me and my current my colleagues) need, and I'm adding things as bugs are filed.

have a look at it now and decide again.  (the web documentation still needs reviewing, for better insight, check the test cases, which are very extensive).

Comment: embedded selects? table aliases? no, not yet available there. but then again, feel free to file a bug report with a non working query and who knows...

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's a very old case, but...

[CsvJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) is a cool library, but there are some issues using [DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/) while mapping ResultsSets to PoJos.
A second bad thing is, that dosn't have a good support for different Datatypes.

After playing with [CSVJdbc](http://csvjdbc.sourceforge.net/) I will use a stupid CsvParser to read the Files an pump them into a HsqlDB or something like that.

Comment: have you reported the issues with csvjdbc? the current maintainer (not me any more) is very prompt in picking up serious issues.

Comment: No I haven't. I'am not able to create a ticket there.

Comment: you should be able to create a ticket there once you log in / register. anonymous users are not allowed to create nor update tickets. I guess in order to avoid spammers... but be more specific, what "some issues" you met, and what "good support" you expect?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Groovy script, gcsvsql that lets you treat csv files as database tables, including joins.   With gcsvsql you can do things like:

> gcsvsql "select * from people.csv
>   where age > 40"
>
> gcsvsql "select
>   people.name,children.child from
>   people.csv,children.csv where
>   people.name=children.name"
>
> gcsvsql "select avg(score) from
>   people.csv where age < 40"

You can find this script, which is based on the h2 database engine, at Google code here:

http://code.google.com/p/gcsvsql/